# Что имеют в виду, когда говорят, что большинство популярных сервисов написаны на Django?

Tags: django

Меня интересует то, по какой причине все говорят, что Инстаграм и прочие популярные гиганты написаны на Django?
Django сам по себе медленный и меня покрывают сомнения когда я слышу и вижу подобного рода рассуждения. Может утверждающие имеют в виду, что в качестве API используется DRF, а Django как веб-клиент, обращающийся к нему? Проясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: я сомневаюсь в достоверности этой статьи, ну или я неправильно понял. Что у них вся логика помещена в одном джанго проекте? Не может быть. Куда тогда запросы посылаются и как происходит работа с их API?

Comment: вот источник получше https://instagram-engineering.com/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of-technologi    We run Django on Amazon High-CPU Extra-Large machines

Comment: спасибо. но все равно неясно куда посылаются запросы при открытии той же страницы с списком подписчиков

Comment: и каким образом они привели приложения под разные операционные системы к общему знаменателю? переписывали всю логику?

Comment: ссылка чёто сбилась https://instagram-engineering.com/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of-technologies-adf2e22da2ad

Comment: Обычно логика пишется на джанго а статика отдается nginx например. Что скрашивает вопросы скорости. Плюс формирование кеша. Но как у них там построена инфраструктура вопрос сложный. Думаю там много чего переписано.